# Set Fixed Save As Type for a Save As Macro

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I've been working in this macro, the only thing that I need to do is to save the Final sheet into a CSV file.

The problem is that I need to choose the path and the name of the file. I've managed to open the pop up window to save it, but I need to set fixed the CSV value, is it possible?

Here's my code

```
    Sub Fin()
        Sheets("COI").Select
        Columns("A:O").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Final").Select
        Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
           :=True, Transpose:=False
        On Error Resume Next
        xTitleId = "Selección: "
        Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
        Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
        For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Rng.Value <> "" Then
        If OutRng Is Nothing Then
        Set OutRng = Rng
        Else
        Set OutRng = Union(OutRng, Rng)
        End If
        End If
        Next
        If Not OutRng Is Nothing Then
        OutRng.Select
        End If
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Select
        If MsgBox("¿Está seguro de haber rellenado correctamente la plantilla?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
        MsgBox "Se ha guardado correctamente.", vbInformation
      End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show, xlCSV
```

Should get you started. You should consider assigning the value to a variable.

Comment: It works, but in the end it creates also a file named TRUE or FALSE, wheter I click the accept or de cancel button; and also the save as type is not choosed CSV by default.